# Testing nested JSX with React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to run a test where I can validate that a userList prop is being rendered. As of now when I run screen.debug(), it shows all the HTML except the HTML inside the nested brackets in the body of the code within the return area. Below is my test and the component (UserList) that is using it.

```js
describe("The App component", () => {
  it("renders a UserList component",  async () => {
    render(<UsersList userList={[{id: 0, title: "asdf"}, {id: 1, title: "zxcv"}]}/>);
    const ul = await screen.getByRole("list");
    expect(ul.childElementCount > 0).toBe(true);
  })
})
```

```js
import * as React from "react";

const UsersList = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {
          props.usersList ? props.usersList.map((user: any) => {
              return (
                <li key={user.id}>{user.title}</li>
              )
            })
            : null
        }
      </ul>
    </>
  )
}

export default UsersList
```

With the following error:

```
    ✕ renders a UserList component (9 ms)

  ● The App component › renders a UserList component

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: true
    Received: false

      28 |     render(<UsersList userList={[{id: 0, title: "asdf"}, {id: 1, title: "zxcv"}]}/>);
      29 |     const ul = await screen.getByRole("list");
    > 30 |     expect(ul.childElementCount > 0).toBe(true);
         |                                      ^
      31 |   })
      32 | })

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/tests/App.test.tsx:30:38)
```

Comment: I think you misspelled the props for `userList` instead of `usersList`?

Comment: yep, little typos like that have been getting me bad lately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the actual prop that `UsersList` component expects is `usersList` so you have to pass the right prop in your test:

```
describe("The App component", () => {
    it("renders a UserList component",  async () => {
        render(<UsersList usersList={[{id: 0, title: "asdf"}, {id: 1, title: "zxcv"}]}/>);
        const ul = await screen.getByRole("list");
        expect(ul.childElementCount > 0).toBe(true);
    })
})
```